# With SoapUI 5.5.0 (not ReadyAPI) log into JSP Formular Authentication

Tags: jsp, soapui

I try to write a test for a REST in SoapUI 5.5.0 and will call a OracleDB generated JSP Formular to connect the REST Webservice inside the Database, but i didn't know how i can solve the Problem.
It is a JSP Basic Formular authentication with standardfields like j_username and j_password.
The User is created in ORDS and with the Browser it works fine.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Ask your developers to add an authentication service/method, or use a Groovy script step with SQL to authenticate directly in the database if possible. If they want you to test it with SoapUI they must meet you halfway. Alternatively, you can use java-selenium in a Groovy step to render the form in a browser and get an authentication token.

Comment: i have all information, because i create the authentication within ORDS and activate the Role-Authentication inside the DB
i try to find a way, to use SoapUI

Comment: Then you can do it in SQL in a Groovy script step in SoapUI, like I said in my first sentence.

Comment: Did you have some workbook or something else, where i can read and show for how it is to do?